# Mouse lagging in Ubuntu-mate 19.04 in Virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, 19.04, ubuntu-mate

Why mouse is lagging in Ubuntu-mate 19.04 unlike Ubuntu-mate 18.04.02 in virtual machine? VM is Oracle VirtualBox.

You can see this even then you installing these. In 19.04 is like it make low fps or something like this. But in 18.04.02 mouse pointer moving and redrawing pretty well!

I downloaded the OS images from official site. Virtual machine settings are same!

Has anyone had this? This lag is so annoying, but I want to use last version.

Comment: Just asking: Did you install *VirtualBox Guest Additions* to the guest machine?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli No, in both systems. But 18.04 works well out of the box. Ok, Now I will try to install it and see.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli 19.04 said that additions is already installed, and just suggest me to reinstall it (By "Insert Guest Additions CD image"). apt-get said same for this package `virtualbox-guest-x11 is already the newest version (6.0.6-dfsg-1).` It is fresh clear just installed system.